# Reducing Isolation Transformer Leakage

Tags: transformer, mains, isolation, leakage-current

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3nOkjB-uRU) and wonder if its complete separation of primary and secondary coils is the normal way to wind a low-power isolation transformer (e.g., 60Hz 120V 120VA).

I particularly want low isolation leakage (i.e., the DC leakage from the primary to secondary coil) and believe the winding method of the video should easily keep this leakage below 1uA (at room temperature) if normal insulators are used between the coils.  So, it therefore surprises me that normal retail isolation transformers advertise leakage on the order of 100uA (even [medical grade versions](https://tripplite.eaton.com/isolator-series-120v-250w-ul60601-1-medical-grade-isolation-transformer-2-hospital-grade-outlets%7EIS250HG) measure more than 10uA).

So, where physically is this leakage in retail isolation transformers?

What is the performance tradeoff if I tried to minimize isolation leakage further?
If my goal is 1nA, what do I need to sacrifice?

Comment: The leakage current in the transformer specifications is not just DC current, it is also AC current, which is the result of capacitive coupling between the windings. This can be reduced significantly by putting a grounded electrostatic shield between the windings.

Comment: ... or strongly exacerbated, should you require a capacitor across the isolation to return switch noise to meet EMI

Comment: @DaveTweed The medical grade linked to above mentions nothing about their 100uA limit including AC.  What do you expect its DC leakage to be?

Comment: DC leakage for transformers, if specced, is usually >>1e10 ohm.

Comment: @tobalt But, why does this video measure (about 14 minutes in) about 50uA DC? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek_GrhY7r5A

Comment: Now that I look at it more closely, maybe that is a 60 Hz ~100pF capacitive charging current and not the leakage I am thinking about.  So, is the official isolation leakage spec always for 60 Hz?